# How to count a leap year, when calculating dates in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to plus some days for the date. When I use this code, I miss a leap year. How not to miss it?

```
import java.time.LocalDate

LocalDate dob = LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1).plusDays(40176)
```

Comment: What does "I miss a leap year" mean? What do you want to achieve, what is the expected result and why? What is the actual result?

Comment: @JB Nizet, For example, when I plus 36212, I receive the date "1999.02.23", but the date must be "1999.02.22"

Comment: So you think that the standard Java library has a bug. I'd rather think that your computation is incorrect. When do you think a year is a leap year?

Comment: @JB Nizet, sorry, it's my mistake. I got a problem with calculations